# How to migrate customizations to newer version of Bugzilla

Tags: bugzilla

Where can I find information on migrating our customized pages from our current install of Bugzilla to the latest, Bugzilla 3.6?

I'm trying to get up to speed on how all of of the pieces come together to make Bugzilla work. I have a working installation of 3.6 in a VHD (we are running on Windows). Next, I just need to figure out how to move our customizations forward.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several categories of stuff that you must consider how to move forward:

- changes to scripts and modules

If you've been making changes to the code directly, it should be just a matter of merging 3.6 onto your source tree.  This can create a number of conflicts, and it can be an exercise in code archaeology to figure out the resolution.

Use this as an opportunity to jump on the code hooks bandwagon so that you have minimal (hopefully no) changes to Mozilla's source, which will make future upgrades a lot easier.

- changes to templates

If you've been changing templates in `template/en/default`, then that's pretty much the same as the case above - you need to merge in Mozilla's changes.  If you've been putting customizations into `template/en/custom`, then you need to evaluate whether you need to make any changes based on corresponding changes to the defaults.

- changes to extensions

3.6 introduces some new architecture in the extension system.  You'll probably want to dig into this page as much as I have:

http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.6/en/html/api/Bugzilla/Extension.html

You'll probably also want to look at the upgrading notes for 3.6:

http://www.bugzilla.org/releases/3.6/release-notes.html#v36_upgrading

Finally, what I didn't notice until I had manually converted an extension, there's a script that will do it for you!

http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.6/en/html/api/contrib/extension-convert.html

You may find it helpful to visit #mozwebtools on irc.mozilla.org.  That's where all the cool Bugzilla kids hang out!  They're happy to chat up customizations to your heart's content.